# jQuery Unresponsive Script due to getWidthOrHeight function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the past few weeks my users and I are getting the following message. Happens only in Firefox.

> Warning:Unresponsive script
>
> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the >script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js:6803

I tried replacing jQuery 1.7.1 with 1.7.2 but it didn't help. Still getting the message.
The line referes to a function called getWidthOrHeight. While debugging I wasn't able to find any issue with the code.

```
function getWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra ) {

// Start with offset property
var val = name === "width" ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.offsetHeight,
    i = name === "width" ? 1 : 0,
    len = 4;

if ( val > 0 ) {
    if ( extra !== "border" ) {
        for ( ; i < len; i += 2 ) {


            if ( !extra ) {    //This is the problematic line causing the unresponsive error. 


                val -= parseFloat( jQuery.css( elem, "padding" + cssExpand[ i ] ) ) || 0;
            }
            if ( extra === "margin" ) {
                val += parseFloat( jQuery.css( elem, extra + cssExpand[ i ] ) ) || 0;
            } else {
                val -= parseFloat( jQuery.css( elem, "border" + cssExpand[ i ] + "Width" ) ) || 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return val + "px";
}
```

Furthermore, this problem started without performing any change in the code calling the jQuery.

When I tried it with jQuery 1.7.1 I got the error on line 6778 which is the same one as mentioned above.

The error usually appears on the first run of the browser when loading after a restart.

Could this be caused due to a problem with Firefox? How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Found this post by Mozilla but it doesn't solve it. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script

Comment: do you have a link to the project so we can take a look? we may not be able to help with only this amount of code to go on.

Comment: It happens on this page. http://www.allmyfaves.com/example

Comment: ok, so what version of FF are you using?

Comment: 18.0.1 but it also happened in 17 and I think that also 16. Keep in mind that it is not consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Also experienced similar issues on one of our websites. You can use the script validator on [w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) to see how to fix these errors...really helped me a lot.